# How to write protocol oriented sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, associated-types

This is just a mockup of my real example, my rows are complex objects

My tableview has different section types.

```
enum Type{
    case devices
    case users
    case status
}
```

Obviously each section has some rows, may have a headerTitle and has a sectionType, I've tried to generalize that as much as I can. Not sure if using `associatedType` is the right way...probably there's a much simpler solution for just using protocols

```
protocol SectionType{
    associatedtype Section
    associatedtype Rows

    init(sectionType: Section, rows: Rows)

    var sectionType: Section {get set}
    var rows: Rows  {get set}
    var headerTitle: String? {get set}
}
```

The main problem is that is the rows of each Section can be **entirely** different (more than the difference between `customObject1` and `customObject2`) One solution is to just do `var rows: Any` and then cast back, but that's not really a good idea.

```
class CustomObject1{
    var number: Int

}

class CustomObject2{
    var name : String?

}
```

My conformance to the protocol:

```
class SomeSection: SectionType{

    var sectionType: Type
    var rows: [CustomObject1]
    var headerTitle: String?

    required init(sectionType: Type, rows: [CustomObject1]){
        self.sectionType = sectionType
        self.rows = rows
    }
}
```

As you can see my `SomeSection` *class*  is useless, it's only workable for 
`CustomObject1`

```
var dataSource : [SectionType] = []

let firstSection = SomeSection(sectionType: .devices, rows: [CustomObject1(), CustomObject1(),CustomObject1()])
let secondSection = SomeSection(.users, rows: [???????]) // I can't add `CustomObject2` instances...nor I think creating a new class is a good idea


dataSource.append(firstSection)
dataSource.append(secondSection)
tableview.datasource = dataSource
```

How can I resolve this?

---

**EDIT**

I think my protocol approach was totally unnecessary. However now I have a different problem. My viewController was previously like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
var dataSource : [Section] = []

}
```

now I have to change it to:

```
class ViewController<Row>: UIViewController{
var dataSource : [Section<Row>] = []

}
```

right?

The problem right now with the approach that Rich has suggested is that I can't `apppend` these two instances of the Generic class into a single array, because their generic properties types are eventually not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do based on your code. Are you saying that each row of each section is static and not dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can simplify the solution by using a generic class for this  use case, but if you want to use protocols and associated types, the following should work:

```
protocol SectionType {
  associatedtype Section
  associatedtype Row

  init(sectionType: Section, rows: [Row]) 
  var sectionType: Section {get set}
  var rows: [Row]  {get set}
  var headerTitle: String? {get set}
}

class SomeSection<T,U>: SectionType{
  typealias Section = T
  typealias Row = U

  var sectionType: Section
  var rows: [Row]
  var headerTitle: String?

  required init(sectionType: Section, rows: [Row]){
    self.sectionType = sectionType
    self.rows = rows
  }
}

enum FoodType {
  case cheese
  case beer
}

enum Currency {
  case dollars
  case pounds
}

let s1 = SomeSection(sectionType: FoodType.cheese, rows: ["cheddar", "stilton"])
let s2 = SomeSection(sectionType: FoodType.beer, rows: ["rochefort12", "Spring Sprinter"])
let s3 = SomeSection(sectionType: Currency.dollars, rows: [1,2])
```

The generic version would just be:

```
class SomeSection<Section,Row> {
  var sectionType: Section
  var rows: [Row]
  var headerTitle: String?

  required init(sectionType: Section, rows: [Row]){
    self.sectionType = sectionType
    self.rows = rows
  }
}
```

which might be better if the class isn't required to implement any other functionality

Comment: Didn't know the typeAlias used for the associatedType can still be generic type. If that's the case, can't we just use generic parameters on the class and forget `typeAlias`-ing. Does your 'generic class' approach mean that?